# How to automatically play a video when the URL is loaded into the player?

Tags: jquery, html5-video, attr

I'm having a problem with my code on cloning a url in a div into a video player. The problem I'm having is that it's suppose to automatically play when the URL is loaded. The URL is loaded but won't play.

How do you trigger the play button when a URL is loaded into a player?

JS Code:

```js
$("#next-item").on("click", function() {
var mp3Url = $("#video-ID-1").data('rel');
    $("#video-to-play").attr('src', mp3Url);
    $('#video-to-play video').trigger('play');
});
```

```css
video {width:480px;height:auto}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="next-item" class="button">Next</button>
<div id="video-ID-1" class="slider-slide-wrap video-post" data-rel="https://ia601401.us.archive.org/3/items/5sec-sound-test/5sec%20sound%20test.mov">
  <div class="media-contain">
    <video preload="auto" id="video-to-play" onloadstart="this.volume=0.5" src="#"></video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the " video" in the jquery selector of the trigger. Like this :

```
$('#video-to-play').trigger('play');
```

You can also use the html "autoplay" attribute to always start the video automatically :

```
<video preload="auto" id="video-to-play" onloadstart="this.volume=0.5" src="#" autoplay></video>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Adding `autoplay` to the video worked.

Comment: Be careful, the "autoplay" attribute does not work in some mobile devices like iPad and iPhone. So if you wish to use it on these devices the first solution is better.